# Understanding unit testing for dynamically changing condition

Tags: testing, unit-testing, exception-handling

I was trying to understand how to write unit tests for a few days now. I'm confused with  following scenarios in the existing code.

In first function the max value changes depending on the object created at run time but in the second case it is a constant.

NOTE: The following functions are not related. These are two different scenarios.

```cs
SomeFunction1(arg1,....)
{
  if(arg1 > someObject.MaxAllowedValue)
  {
     throw exception;
  }
}
```

```cs
SomeFunction2(arg1,....)
{
  if(arg1 > maxAllowedValue)
  {
     throw exception;
  }
}
```

I am trying to test whether the function throws an exception when max value is exceeded.

Does the unit test remain the same in both the cases or is it different?

Comment: what is someObject? where it come from changes a lot of things in your code.

Comment: someObject is dynamically created and changes in each execution. To be more specific it is dependent on the hardware(which our software drives) connected to our system. Different hardware results in different someObject and thus a different MaxAllowedValue.

Comment: If `someObject` depends on the hardware, I'd follow DaveFar's advice and mock it.

Comment: How do you plan on controling all the values for each test? One test isn't going to account for all the possible values of someObject.MaxAllowedValue. You just need one that passess the test.

Comment: @Scroog1 How does mock help? I can mock one object at a time. Let me put it with an example. Lets say my args1 value is 10. Different mock objects have different max values. Some more than 10 and some less. In that case when the actual code runs if condition execution depends on the object at that moment. How does my test ensure that?

Comment: Mocking would allow you to define `someObject`'s `MaxAllowedValue` for the given test without having to worry about which hardware you are running the test on.  If your `arg1` is `10`, then you only really need to test with 10 and 9 for `MaxAllowedValue`.

Comment: @Scroog1 Thanks. Ok now I seem to get it. But out of curiosity what if tommorrow someone changes the if condition to if(10 > someObject.MaxAllowedValue), the tests still pass. I know it is insane but it is possible. What then? How to handle it?

Comment: @mssrivatsa that's a good point.  I got slightly too focused on the variation of `MaxAllowedValue`.  As `arg1` is variable, you should, of course, also test for suitable different values of that too.  Then someone changing the code as you suggested will cause failing tests.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend somewhat on where `someObject` came from and how its property value changes.  But assuming that `someObject.MaxAllowedValue` and `maxAllowedValue` have the same value, the test will remain the same.  Remember, you are testing the behaviour of `SomeFunctionX`, not the implementation details.

Comment: No, both values are not same. Both functions are not even related code wise. Only relation between them is that they have same if condition. someObject.MaxAllowedValue depends on someObject and different for different executions of this function.
Should the test be written for each different someObject in that case?

Comment: As Telastyn as said in another comment, you only need to test the two cases: exception should be thrown and exception shouldn't; it doesn't really matter which value of `sameObject` you choose to do it with.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: 1) refactor your code 2) mock `someObject`

#### Refactor your code

Congraz, you are just unit testing for a few days now and have learned one of the most important aspects of unit testing (especially when done early in the development process):

> ```
> The act of writing a unit test is more an act of design 
> than of verification.
> ```
>
> (Uncle Bob, [Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0135974445))

So if `SomeFunction1` and `SomeFunction2` have closely related functionality and concerns, refactor them into one method. If not, you also need to write different unit tests for them since they cover different functionality/concerns.

#### Mock

If your code still contains

```
if(arg1 > someObject.MaxAllowedValue)
```

think about whether your current unit test should also test `someObjects` (probably not). If not, you should mock it, e.g. with [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) ([this cheat sheet is helpful for both junit and EasyMock](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/junit-and-easymock)).

Update: Since you are testing another class, not that of someObject, it does not matter that someObject changes at runtime. All you have to do is cover all possible behaviors of your implementation under test with your tests, e.g.

- arg1 == someObject.MaxAllowedValue
- arg1 == someObject.MaxAllowedValue+1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should have been clear because the two functions are not related. So refactor doesn't apply. Second, I am mocking the object. But object differs from execution to execution. In such cases how should a test be written?

Comment: @mssrivatsa - You should test the rule "if more than max, throw" (and also that less than or equal to does not throw). It doesn't matter how the max is created, the test should control that and verify the rule.

Comment: @Telastyn Ok, so that should be the only check by the unit test, whether there is exception or not irrespective of how data is created?

Comment: exactly, mssrivatsa. I updated my answer.